# upload byte array to server

Tags: c#, xamarin.android

I already converted the image to byte array like this :

```
Stream stream = ContentResolver.OpenInputStream(data.Data);
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.DecodeStream(stream);
MemoryStream memStream = new MemoryStream();
bitmap.Compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.Jpeg, 50, memStream);                
byte[] picData;
picData = memStream.ToArray();
```

How do upload picData to the server in folder "Pictures"

Thanks advanced

Comment: From your device to your server, you mean?

Comment: Logically you have to POST this byte array to an endpoint to your server, that would handle the rest.

Comment: Thanks all , yes Rene, from device android to server. Christos, how to do it please?

Comment: can give this a try using(WebClient client = new WebClient()) {
    client.UploadFile(address, filePath);
}